# how to post json objects to webservices like url

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, post

I want to pass JSON objects to web services like this

```
firstname=jhon&lastname=mic&mail=jhon@gmail.com&sex=M&hometown=blablabla
```

how can I pass,any one please help me.Am trying like this

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("firstname", firstname);
        json.put("lastname", laststname);
         json.put("mail", mail);
        json.put("sex", sex);
        json.put("hometown", hometown)


  HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
        post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json1.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));         
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);    

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        if(entity!=null)
        {
            InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
            String result=convertStreamToString(instream);

        }

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)

{

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  String line = null;
  try
  {

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
              sb.append(line + "\n");

      } 
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
      try
      {
          is.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

But this code not posted the right value to webservice,Is there any wrong please help me ,
  Thank you:)

Comment: `firstname=jhon&lastname=mic&mail=jhon@gmail.com&sex=M&hometown=blablabla` is not a JSON, it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ... also there is a plenty similar questions on SO, online tutorials which covering this problem

Comment: oh thank you.i dont know.plese tell me how it post to webservice

Comment: @Selvin: Thank you,my problem is solved.if don't said like that i wasted my entire day.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder bu = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<json.names().length(); i++){
        bu.append("&");
        try {
            bu.append(json.names().getString(i)+"="+json.get(json.names().getString(i)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    bu.toString();//give you parameters
```